# How to analyze processor specification?

Tags: cpu, processor

What does it mean when they say processor is -

- Core i3, i5 or i7?
- Core 2 Duo or Dual Core?
- CPU @ 3.20 GHz or similar GHz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up everything a bit :

Core i3, i5, i7, 2 Duo are **brand names** used by Intel for families of processors it builds.

A dual core processor (or more generally multi-core) is a processor which features **multiple processing units**. This allows to have multiple threads (i.e. somehow a list of consecutive instructions to be executed), so that 2 or more instruction can be executed at a time.

3.20 GHz is the **frequency** of the clock of the processor. It is in Hertz (Hz). A higher frequency for a processor with the exact same components while make the processor execute instructions faster (most of the time). However, a processor with a high frequency will not necessarly be faster than a processor with a lower frequency.

---

See :

- [Multi-core processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor)
- [Clock rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_rate)
- [Intel core](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_core)

Answer (score 0):

These are names and types of different processors. The vary in the number of cores and clock rate.

The number of the cores is the number of unites which do actually add values. (See ALU)

The clock rate shows how many additions the CPU can make in a specified time.

Help yourself and read:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Intel_processors
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_AMD_processors